# ¿Cuál es el origen de la palabra "horchata"?

Tags: etimología, historia, comida

La horchata es una bebida hecha de chufas que se produce especialmente en la zona de Valencia, en España.

Siempre había oído la siguiente anécdota sobre su origen: una vez un rey visitó la zona y, en un momento dado, una joven le dio la famosa *horchata* para que la probara. Tanto le gustó que dijo *Això és or, xata!* en catalán (*esto es oro, chata*). Al no conocer el idioma, se quedó con lo de *or xata* y entendió que la bebida se llamaba *orxata* o, castellanizado, *horchata*.

Sin embargo, leo en Twitter lo siguiente que tiraría por tierra esta leyenda:

> La HORCHATA DE CHUFA u ORXATA es una bebida típica de Valencia y alrededores, que remonta su nombre a la denominación latina del agua de cebada, "hordeata", de "hordeum", "cebada". Parece ser que su llegada a través del mozárabe explica el cambio de "d" a "ch" y la conservación
> de la "t" final, pues una evolución fonética regular habría dado algo parecido a "horzada". Es apócrifo el origen que lo relaciona supuestamente con el rey Jaume I de Aragón, quien, según la leyenda, habría exclamado, tras probar la bebida que una valenciana le había ofrecido,
> habría exclamado "Això és or, xata!" ("¡Esto es oro, chata!"). De ese "or, xata" habría derivado ORXATA. Sin embargo, XATA resulta anacrónico en el siglo XIII, pues es un castellanismo reciente derivado de CHATA, con lo que la historia, sin fundamento histórico, nunca tuvo lugar.
>
> <sub>Etimologías en [Twitter, 23 de septiembre de 2020](https://twitter.com/EtimosDirectos/status/1308738947158286338)</sub>

Efectivamente, la palabra
Miré [en el DLE](https://dle.rae.es/horchata) y va en la misma línea:

> Del lat. hordeāta 'hecha con cebada', der. de hordeum 'cebada', quizá por conducto mozár.

Así pues, ¿es este su verdadero origen? ¿Vino efectivamente del mozárabe?

Comment: Igual de interesante es la evolución de su significado. En 1734 el _Autoridades_ definía la palabra así: "Bebida que se hace de pepítas de melón y calabaza, con algunas almendras, todo machacado y exprimido con água, y sazonado con azúcar. Dixose assí quasi Hordeata, porque las más veces se hace con água de cebada." Ni rastro de chufas por ningún lado.

Comment: Os lo dejo como dato Curioso: En México se prepara una bebida típica llamada “agua de orchata” y está hecha con arroz molido con agua, azúcar y vainilla. También hay gente que prepara la bebida con las semillas de melón, pero no le llaman horchata.

Answer (score 5):

Según la Wikipedia en su artículo sobre el [mozárabe](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idioma_moz%C3%A1rabe), efectivamente parece que este idioma palatalizó en *ch* los grupos *-ci-*, *-ti-* y otros. Cita los siguientes nombres de localidades como ejemplos (entre otros):

```
latín            mozárabe      español
---------------------------------------------------
caravantellu     Qarabanchel   Carabanchel (Madrid)
villa martiana   Marchiana     Marchena (Sevilla)​
monasteriu       Monacheyr     Monachil (Granada)
```

A la vista de estos ejemplos, parece plausible que el grupo *-di-* en *ordiata* sufriera una evolución parecida, y no seré yo quien contradiga a los expertos. Sin embargo, hay un detalle que no sé cómo encaja en esta historia: el mozárabe se considera una lengua muerta desde el siglo XIII, y las primeras apariciones en textos de la palabra *horchata* son del siglo XVIII. Eso quiere decir que la palabra *horchata* debió estar rondando la expresión oral en la península durante al menos 500 años, o bien que pasara antes por otros idiomas previos.

En el CORDE el primer caso que encuentro es el siguiente:

> *Las pepitas bebidas en horchata, quiebran la vejiga, según dicen y afirman algunos autores.*
>
> Juan José Delgado, "Historia general sacro-profana, política y natural de las islas del Poniente llamadas Filipinas", c 1754 (Filipinas).

En la hemeroteca de la Biblioteca Nacional de España, el primer caso es el siguiente:

> *[...] tomando encima, por tarde y noche, un vaso de la horchata nitrada, echa de las semillas frias [...].*
>
> Memorial literario instructivo y curioso de la Corte de Madrid. 11/1785, [página 44](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0012140609&page=44&search=horchata&lang=es).

Y en diccionarios el primer caso lo constituye el encontrado en el Diccionario de Autoridades, tomo G-M de 1734:

> HORCHATA. s. f. Bebida que se hace de pepítas de melón y calabaza, con algunas almendras, todo machacado y exprimido con água, y sazonado con azúcar. Dixose assi quasi Hordeata, porque las más veces se hace con água de cebáda.

Un poco antes se recoge la voz *orchata* en el *Sobrino* de 1705, traduciendo la voz al francés *orgeade*.

Antes de 1700 lo único que encuentro en diccionarios son variantes del término original latino. Se puede encontrar *ordeáta* en el *Minsheu* de 1617 y *ordiata* en el *Palet* de 1604, en ambos casos con una acepción similar a la de "tisana". De hecho hoy en día el DLE recoge la voz siguiente como heredera de aquellas:

> **[hordiate](https://dle.rae.es/hordiate)**
>
> Del cat. *ordiat*, y este del lat. *hordeātus*, der. de *hordeum* 'cebada'.
>
> 1. m. Cebada mondada.
> 2. m. Bebida que se hace de cebada, semejante a la tisana.

Esto es lo que hace que me resulte extraño pensar en que una voz de origen mozárabe haya aparecido de repente en el siglo XVIII partiendo de un idioma muerto cinco siglos atrás. No hay rastro de la palabra antes de dicho siglo, solo términos para las bebidas de cebada similares a la tisana.

Sobre la posibilidad de que venga del italiano, la Wikipedia menciona que la evolución natural de la voz latina habría derivado en español en algo parecido a *orzad*, similar a *orzata*. De ahí que se suponga el origen mozárabe viendo la transformación en *ch* del grupo intermedio al tiempo que se mantiene la *t* final. Se podría descartar entonces que la voz española provenga de la italiana.

Pero volviendo a esa palabra francesa *orgeade* que hemos visto antes, tratando de buscar su origen me encuentro con que en el [francés medio](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franc%C3%A9s_medio), considerado de uso entre 1340 y 1611, existió la palabra *[orgeat](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/ORGEAT)* con el significado de "cebada en grano", "brebaje para enfermos, a base de sémola de cebada, almendras y azúcar", y "leche de cebada". Me llama la atención especialmente ese segundo significado, similar al ofrecido por el *Autoridades* en 1734. Entre la similitud en la definición y el parecido entre *orgeat* y *horchata*, ¿pudiera ser que la voz *horchata*, como tantas otras y sobre todo dado el siglo en el que se redactó el *Autoridades*, viniera de Francia? Según el etimológico del CNRTL, *[orgeat](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/orgeat)* viene de *[orge](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/orge)*, palabra que ya existía en el siglo XII con el significado de "cebada". Por tanto, personalmente me parece más plausible la evolución siguiente:

- Latín *hordeum*, 'cebada'.
- Francés antiguo *orge*, 'cebada'.
- Francés medio *orgeat*, 'bebida de cebada, almendras y azúcar', posiblemente por influencia del latín *hordeata*.
- Español *[h]orchata*, 'bebida de cebada, almendras, pepitas de melón y azúcar', posiblemente por influencia del italiano *orzata* o la propia voz latina *hordeata*.

Esto explicaría además por qué en algunos textos y diccionarios se encuentra la versión *orchata*, sin la *h* inicial, por semejanza a la palabra francesa original, al tiempo que la versión con *h* por semejanza a su original latino.

El propio Corominas recoge esta posibilidad en su diccionario etimológico. Simplemente, a él le parecía más plausible la evolución mozárabe, y argumenta que si la palabra proviniera del idioma occitano (el cual considera originario de la voz *orgeat* en francés), en español habríamos esperado la voz *horchate*. Considera pues esto una teoría forzada, aunque más forzado me parece a mí que no exista documentación sobre la horchata anterior al siglo XVIII (como el propio Corominas reconoce) y pretender que venga influenciada por un idioma muerto cinco siglos atrás. Que una palabra evolucione a *horchata* en vez de a *horchate*, tal vez por semejanza del italiano *orzata*, que el propio Corominas afirma que se documenta ya en el siglo XVI y que el sonido de la *z* italiana podría haber derivado "caprichosamente" en la *ch* española, no es motivo para pretender que la teoría sea forzada o que haya que descartarla en favor de otras, en mi humilde opinión, más forzadas aún.

Comment: Excelente aportación, Charlie. No recordaba yo la Hemeroteca Digital, de ahí encontré [un artículo](https://www.degustalarioja.com/rica-antigua-horchata-20190810235634-ntvo.html) que menciona _El agua de cebada fue una bebida popular ya en tiempos de los romanos y durante la Edad Media se le atribuyeron propiedades refrescantes, analgésicas y de aumento de la secreción de leche_. De ahí que también aparezca en muchas entradas del CORDE como "jarabe". Sobre la etimología, la hipótesis del mozárabe también me cojea, la del francés + ortografía italiana parece la más plausible.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' gracias, no todos los días tiene uno la inspiración para rebatir al gran Corominas. :-D La bebida de cebada que menciona el artículo sería lo que hoy conocemos como "hordiate", la "horchata" partiría de este hordiate y le añadió más cosas (almendras, pepitas de melón), y en algún momento pasaría de hacerse con agua de cebada a usar agua de chufas. Igual algún día busco una receta antigua de la horchata de pepitas de melón y la hago en casa.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' gracias por tus palabras al respecto de la recompensa, no sabes cuánto me alegra el reconocimiento y haber sido de ayuda. Y por cierto, he enviado a la RAE copia de esta respuesta, por si la consideran digna de estudio para [modificar el diccionario](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4370/12637).

Comment: ¡A ti por el currazo! Copio aquí el motivo de la recompensa, para que siga disponible cuando se otorgue: _es difícil saber el origen "definitivo", pero la ejemplar investigación y explicación de la respuesta de Charlie merece un gran aplauso que transmito con esta recompensa_. Ojalá la RAE considere la sugerencia.

Answer (score 2):

El diccionario etimológico de Corominas indica:

> HORCHATA,  del  lat.  HORDEATA  'hecha  con  cebada',  derivado  de  HORDEUM  'cebada',  aunque **no está  bien  averiguada  la  procedencia  inmediata  del vocablo**,  que  podría  ser  tomado  del  italiano  *orzata*,  pero  más  bien  **parece  ser  un  mozarabismo, quizá  de  origen  valenciano**.